# Navigation View in drawer layout-menu items do not appear

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the java file which seems to work fine is there anything im missing here?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
    public View decorView ;
    private MapView mapView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        decorView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.accesstoken1));

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the account manager
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                // Customize map with markers, polylines, etc.

            }
        });
        //addDrawerItems();
       // mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Set the list's click listener
        //mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    }

    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);}
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        toggle.syncState();
    }

}
```

and here is my xml which has a navigationview in the drawerlayout

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/amariv/ciz4jb3i0005m2spdp1p2fkfi"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu which has each item that i want in the menu but doesnt appear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/MyEvents"
        android:title="My Locations"

    />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/AddEvent"
        android:title="Add Event"

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Navpath"
        android:title="Directions"

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/LocalizeView"
        android:title="Localize View"

        />


</menu>
```

Comment: the drawer actualy works its just when it opens there are no items.

Answer (score 0):

the navigation view will be drawn below the content of the activity, your navigation view element should be written last in the drawerLayout.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/amariv/ciz4jb3i0005m2spdp1p2fkfi"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```